# OSM Tile server hosting

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04, openstreetmap, mapnik

I followed [this](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) link to host an OSM tile server. But once I reach the last step which is rendering the tiles

sudo -u username renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf

I get this

> An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource for type: 'shape'  encountered during parsing of layer 'land-low' in Layer at line 48 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'renderd[2728]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource for type: 'shape'  encountered during parsing of layer 'land-low' in Layer at line 48 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'
>
> renderd[2728]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource for type: 'shape'  encountered during parsing of layer 'land-low' in Layer at line 48 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'
> renderd[2728]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource for type: 'shape'  encountered during parsing of layer 'land-low' in Layer at line 48 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'

and then try to open localhost/open_tiles/0.0.0.png

I get 'page not found' and

> renderd[2728]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 7, number 1
> renderd[2728]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
> renderd[2728]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(7) xml(default), z(0), x(0), y(0), mime(image/png), options()
> renderd[2728]: Received request for map layer 'default' which failed to load
> renderd[2728]: DEBUG: Sending render cmd(4 default 0/0/0) with protocol version 2 to fd 7
> renderd[2728]: DEBUG: Failed to read cmd on fd 7
> renderd[2728]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 7 closed, now 0 left

I am pretty sure I did all the configuration and the steps mentioned correct. I infact repeated the steps thrice over and still cant get past this error. Please help...

Comment: Offtopic for stackoverflow. But still, the Internet is full of pages and questions with "Could not create datasource for type". Does any of these solutions work for you? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have seen lots of 'Could not create datasource for type' results. But nothing mentions 'during parsing of layer 'land-low'. I have double checked the configuration as well.

Edit: Infact I found one here - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152249/problem-starting-up-tile-server. But my plugin configuration is correct.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the trouble... It was the problem with the plugin directory configuration....Problem is solved....

P.S: Thanks scai for replying...

Comment: I think it depends on the stylesheet whether you are receiving a message for layer land-low or a different one. This solution for a similar problem sounds interesting: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/32583/could-not-create-datasource-for-type-shape-postgis

Comment: Oh, great :) Maybe you can write an answer with a short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I use this config template with caching

```
user www-data;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes auto;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/open-street-map-cache keys_zone=open-street-map-cache:10m;

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www;

    location /osm/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO http;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        add_header X-Cache-Status-Local $upstream_cache_status;

        proxy_pass http://open-street-map:80;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_cache open-street-map-cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 302 90d;
        proxy_cache_valid any 1m;

        proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control     Set-Cookie;

        client_body_buffer_size 10m;
        client_max_body_size 10m;
    }
  }
}
```